# MAAS IPMI power password

Tags: maas, ipmi

I'm trying to run `ipmipower -D LAN_2_0 -h 192.168.13.135 -u maas -p xxx --cycle --on-if-off` command to verify why my MAAS node is failing to deploy an OS, but need to know the maas ipmi power password.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The ipmi password is not something you get out of MAAS.  It something you need to supply to MAAS.  It's set in the management card of the machine you are trying to commission and deploy.  For example, on a DELL server (e.g. R520, R720), the ipmi username and password is an admin account that can log into the iDRAC interface.

This article might be of help:

[How do you add a machine to MAAS with IPMI power using CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939698/how-do-you-add-a-machine-to-maas-with-ipmi-power-using-cli)